# How to simulate from instantaneously correlated Brownian motions?

Tags: brownian-motion, libor-market-model

Say I have obtained a distribution for different forward rates F_k such that:

$$
dF_k (t) = \sigma (t) * F_k (t) * dW_k(t)  
$$
with
$$ dW_k(t) * dW_l(t) = \rho_{k,l} (t) dt.
$$
From this I want to simulate curves for F for k > 50. How do I go about this? It doesnt seem logical to simulate the brownian motions independently, because then how is their covariance taken into account, but I weirdly enough cannot find anything on multidimensional brownian motion simulation.

Comment: Is this what you're after perhaps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Monte_Carlo_simulation

Comment: Check: Cholesky-Banachiewicz Algorithm \\

Here is an [article](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Cholesky-Decomposition-in-Python-and-NumPy/) from Quantstart that explain the algorithm.